# Return email address in GrantSendOnBehalfTo

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to find out list of 'Send On Behalf To' entities for a particular mailbox in our Exchange online setup.
When I run this command in exchange shell, I'm getting just the name of the user (John Doe) and we have multiple John Doe in our organization. This is making it difficult to find out the exact user.
Is there a way to return the GrantSendOnBehalfTo attribute with some unique identifier such as an email?

Command:
`Get-Mailbox -identity "example@example.com" | fl grantsendonbehalfto`

Output:

```
GrantSendOnBehalfTo                     
-------------------                     
{John Doe}
```

Comment: If you notice the `{ }` around the name, this indicates that this is an object and that it has it's own properties. I don't have Exchange so can't give you an exact answer, but if you run `Get-Mailbox -identity "example@example.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty grantsendonbehalfto` this will expand it and show you those properties, one might well be what you want.

Comment: @JamesC. I tried that query the output is same `John Doe` . I'm guessing the brace brackets are because the property is multi valued and on some mailboxes I can see multiple people assigned the send on behalf rights

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the properties you get back on get-mailbox are deserialized, ie no longer live objects. This makes is difficult to retrieve their properties. Try piping the value to Get-User and then getting the distinguishedname or another property that you are looking for.

```
 Get-Mailbox 'first.last@example.org' | select -expandproperty grantsendonbehalfto | get-user | select -expandproperty distinguishedname
```

Answer (score 1):

so for anyone who may come across this, this inspired me with my own solution to the problem in Office365

```
Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $checkDelegate -Properties GrantSendOnBehalfTo | select -ExpandProperty GrantSendOnBehalfTo | foreach-object { $SOB = get-exomailbox -identity $_ | select-object UserPrincipalName,DisplayName }
```

I don't have any duplicate accounts to be able to easily test, but hopefully this helps someone